error: "Property 'Excel.Application.Visible' can not be set
I have a excel file where there is almost 24 macros. Which generate reports for users. I want these report to be shown when user press a button through API. Which I have done in the python.
The issue I am facing is error: "Property 'Excel.Application.Visible' can not be set. Sometime the code works and some time not. Upon futher research I found it is due to their is some cancellation request on the API or Process is not completed. I have to kill the excel application from the server. Then Run it again. and also Excel is only allowing running one instance at a time I can't run the macro for the multiple user at the same time. Kindly suggest me the solution.
Here is the code.
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import os

def close_if_open(file_path):
    # Initialize the COM client
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()

    # Create an instance of Excel
    excel_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

    # Get the full path of the file (in case a relative path is given)
    full_file_path = os.path.abspath(file_path)
    
    # Iterate through the open workbooks in Excel
    for workbook in excel_app.Workbooks:
        # Compare the file paths
        if workbook.FullName == full_file_path:
            print(f"File '{file_path}' is already open. Closing it.")
            # Close the workbook without saving
            workbook.Close(SaveChanges=False)
            break
    else:
        print(f"File '{file_path}' is not open.")
    
    # Quit the Excel application (optional, if you want to close Excel entirely)
    excel_app.Quit()
    
    # Uninitialize the COM client
    pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

# Path to the Excel file
file_path = r'C:\path\to\your\file.xlsx'

# Call the function to check and close the file if it's open
close_if_open(file_path)


Provide the correct logic If I am doing it not according to standards.
Resolve the Error and How to tackle these suitations.


So,It is not an answer but workaround. What I am end up doing is terminating any excel program I have running and regarding the macro timeOut Issue it was due to IIS but increasing the timeactivity parameters did not work for me. What I am end up doing is created a copy of the Project in the Debug mode and Run the Debug APi from the production server. Which done the job workaround but it is working. Thank you.
